# get tag id from foreach loop to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have invoice link for every customer that has been fetched from database.

```
foreach ($customerTables as $value) {
 <td><a id='show' href='invoice.php?invoice=$value->id'>Invoice</a></td>
}
```

so when the user click on the Invoice link, i want to show loading page as follow

```
<p><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></p>
```

and the javascript i use is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
 });
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
 });
```

but it only works for the first row of invoice link. how can i make this to work for every string of invoice? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I will ask a question, how many elements you are supposed to have with the same ID on a single page?

Comment: You have taken `id='show'`, it will be applied to first element. You should try with `class='show'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use id instead of a class. Id's are supposed to be unique so jquery focuses on the first occurence.

try to replace

```
id='show'
```

by

```
class='show'
```

and

```
$("#show").click(function(){
```

by

```
$(".show").click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use same id multiple time in single page so replace it with class like following,

```
foreach ($customerTables as $value) {
 <td><a class='show' href='invoice.php?invoice=$value->id'>Invoice</a></td>
}
```

Also need to give class or id for the p tag that you need to show/hide at the time of clicking the link. Because if you directly hide/show p tag it will effect all other p tag inside that page.So you can use something like below,

```
<p class="loader"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></p>
```

Then you can write your js code like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p.loader").hide();
 });
$(".show").click(function(){
    $("p.loader").show();
 });
```